# How to print a list of pairs without commas between pairs in python?

Tags: python, list, printing

I have two lists of the same size

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and

```
b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would like to print the zipped list `zip(a, b)` but without commas between pairs as follows:

```
c = [(1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, 5) (5, 6)]
```

When I do

```
print(str(list(zip(a, b))).replace(',', ''))
```

I get

```
[(1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6)]
```

which removes all commas even the ones inside each pair, `(1 2)`.

I want the output to be like

```
[(x, y) (z, t) (u, v) ...]
```

Comment: You get exactly what you're asking for, or I've mess something?

Comment: I think we're missing the final expected output to understand  where you solution failed.

Comment: Inside one pair, I do not have commas. Instead I would like to have commas. I do not want to have commas only between pairs.

Comment: Try this:  `" ".join(map(str, zip(a, b)))`  That will also strip the outer square brackets, but you can easily add them back if desired.

Comment: Why do you need that output?

Comment: I need this for LaTeX coordinates (tikz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more specific argument for `replace`:

```
print(str(list(zip(a, b))).replace('), (', ') ('))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("[" + " ".join(map(str, zip(a, b))) + "]")
```

or

```
print("[", " ".join(map(str, zip(a, b))), "]", sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use f-string with str `join`

```
f"[{', '.join([str(e).replace(',','') for e in c])}]"
```

or you can use regular expression:

```
import re 

re.sub('\([^()]*\)', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""), str(c))
```

output:

```
[(1 2), (2 3), (3 4), (4 5), (5 6)]
```